# what's the default size of hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, configuration

We know by default, most of jdbc drivers' fetch sizes are 10.

does anyone know what the default fetch size in hibernate, namely hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size is?

Answer (score 9):

Basically, all the configuration settings are used to build a `o.h.c.Settings` instance. This is done by the `o.h.c.SettingsFactory#buildSettings()` method which contains the following lines:

```
Integer statementFetchSize = PropertiesHelper.getInteger(Environment.STATEMENT_FETCH_SIZE, properties);
if (statementFetchSize!=null) log.info("JDBC result set fetch size: " + statementFetchSize);
settings.setJdbcFetchSize(statementFetchSize);
```

So, a `null` value is allowed, it won't be translated and will be "propagated" as such.

This setting is then used in `o.h.j.AbstractBatcher.java#setStatementFetchSize`:

```
private void setStatementFetchSize(PreparedStatement statement) throws SQLException {
    Integer statementFetchSize = factory.getSettings().getJdbcFetchSize();
    if ( statementFetchSize!=null ) {
        statement.setFetchSize( statementFetchSize.intValue() );
    }
}
```

This private method is called when preparing a `PreparedStatement` or a `CallableStatement`. See `prepareQueryStatement` and `prepareCallableQueryStatement` in `AbstractBatcher`.

So, the default value is `null` and results in Hibernate not calling `Statement#setFetchSize()`.

This is actually summarized in the Reference Documentation:

> #### 3.4. Optional configuration properties
>
> ...
>
> `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`: A non-zero value determines the JDBC fetch size (calls
>   `Statement.setFetchSize()`)

And here is what the javadoc has to say about [`Statement#setFetchSize()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29):

> Gives the JDBC driver a **hint** as to the
>   number of rows that should be fetched
>   from the database when more rows are
>   needed for ResultSet objects genrated
>   by this Statement. If the value
>   specified is zero, then the hint is
>   ignored. **The default value is zero**.

In other words, when using a `null` `fetch_size`, the JDBC driver will use the default value which is **zero**.

Comment: Actually the statement "JDBC driver will use the default value which is zero" is incorrect/impossible. The "fetch size" is the number of rows from the result-set that are fetched from the DB by the driver as results set rows are needed/processed on the client side. If the size were zero it would not fetch any rows. The default by the vast majority of drivers is "10" - which is incidentally VERY LOW for most use-cases and should almost always be overridden commensurate with the use-case for the query in question, balanced by heap memory availability/use.

Comment: The comment above is wrong, "Setting the fetch size back to 0 will cause all rows to be cached (the default behaviour)." https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html 
The default value is zero, and it means fetch all the rows.

Comment: The default value of the _hint_ is zero, but the default value itself in e.g. Oracle is 10: https://vladmihalcea.com/resultset-statement-fetching-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 2):

In JDBC parlance the fetch size is the number of rows physically retrieved from the database at one time by the JDBC driver as you scroll through a query ResultSet with next(). With hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size a non-zero value determines the JDBC fetch size, which in turn calls `java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize()`.

The JDBC fetch size is an optimization hint for the database driver; it may not result in any performance improvement if the driver you're using doesn't implement this functionality. If it does,it can improve the communication between the JDBC client and your database.

See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29 for more info.

Comment: This is a more correct answer. In practice (and I have written drivers in "C"), setFetchSize() is more than a hint in major JDBC drivers (Oracle, IBM, et al). It is critically important for high-performance when processing large result sets across networks where the DB is not on the same host as the JVM (common case). In large production bank systems, I have used this setting to improve performance of JDBC based systems by orders of magnitude. The "hint" part is more about block-sizes where "50" may be implemented as "64" for efficiency for example.

Answer (score 2):

The default is `null`, i.e. no setting. The base implementation of the `Query` interface, `AbstractQueryImpl` internally uses a [RowSelection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.2-Final/org/hibernate/engine/RowSelection.java) to keep track of first row, fetch size and timeout. If these values are `null` then the values are not set on the underlying JDBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate (any JPA implementation) works one level above JDBC driver provided by DB vendor. so if we dont specify fetch size in hibernate configuration, i assume it should take default fetch size configured at JDBC driver level.
Like Oracle - 10, DB2 - 32