# Hibernate is so slow on remoted database (Postgresql)

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate but I'm facing a performance problem with it!
When I use it on a local database it's extremely fast but very slow on a remoted database (**and by remoted database I mean in a local network**)!!
Why?!!

I know you will say maybe it's a lazy loading problem but I have tested it on simple select for one entity (without children) but still slow, check this out:

```
public List<Employee> read() {
        List<Employee> objects = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = HibernateUtil.SESSION.beginTransaction();
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            objects = HibernateUtil.SESSION.createQuery("FROM Employee AS T ORDER BY T.id DESC").list();
            Long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println( "Time: " + (stop - start) + "ms." );
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return objects;
    }
```

As you can see a simple select query and this is the result I get:

**Locally: 31ms**
**Remotely: 356ms !!!!**

And this is my config file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.3:5432/my_database</property>
        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Can you explain this ?

Comment: It is possible that it is a network delay, have a look at your ping to database server.

Comment: it's fast between 8 and 4 ms

Comment: make show_sql true and dump SQLs for a given operation, and try to execute the same queries (read only queries) using a client tool you can cheek whether it is problem related to the network. straight forward way to profile the application with profiler enabled JPA/JDBC (ex: JProfiler). if the target db server is running in a VM (ex VMware), this can be problem in that VM configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [poor Hibernate select performance comparing to running directly - how debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306548/poor-hibernate-select-performance-comparing-to-running-directly-how-debug)

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Not the same man he has problem in his query and he fixed it, but me I just used a simple select query and it's slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need configure a conection pool

Reasons: [The anatomy of Connection Pooling](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling/)

For example, you can use C3P0 with Postgresql:

- [Example 1](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1309)
- [Example 2](https://gazelle.ihe.net/content/how-use-c3p0-jdbc-connection-pool-your-maven-project)

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was a door to learn more about connection pool which is very useful to learn that gives you a better database connection experience. This solved the half of the problem (and the most important one ) the second half is to optimize my queries.
Thnx again :)